# Is it possible to view source code WITHOUT rendering markdown in a .xcplaygroundpage?

Tags: xcode, markdown, swift-playground

In Xcode 8.0, I'm making a playground. Is it possible to view the *real* source of a `.xcplaygroundpage`, i.e. in a sense that does *not* render the markdown in the comments?

Comment: Menu "Editor", "Show raw markup".

Comment: Thanks. Why don't you add it as an answer? :)

Comment: Not sure why I didn't. :) Here it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Playground, to show only code and raw markup, the real source of the file:

> Menu Editor > Show Raw Markup

To display the rendered markup again, with interpreted Markdown and comments:

> Menu Editor > Show Rendered Markup